# Data deletes after runtime, WinForms, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have this simple code that will take a file and insert it into a database. For some reason it won't stay in after runtime. If I try to insert the ID twice during runtime, it throws an error as expected, but when I restart, I can insert the same ID again. Nothing shows on the server explorer.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                // Automatically determine the correct database file path
                string startupPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string mdfPath = Path.Combine(startupPath, "Database1.mdf");

                // Connection string to the database
                string sqlCon = $@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={mdfPath};Integrated Security=True";

                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlCon))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contents (Id, [File]) VALUES (3, @FileData)", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileData", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary, fileData.Length).Value = fileData;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("File added to database");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple ways of inserting. The same problem persists no matter what.

Comment: Never use `AttachDBFileName`. Use `Initial Catalog` instead.

Comment: Could this be the issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031373/executenonquery-is-working-but-changes-are-not-saving

Comment: `AttachDbFilename=` means every time you run your code, you get a new copy of the database. See [When an update doesn't update](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/when-an-update-doesnt-update/).